# Stuck translating a Python algorithm into C++

Tags: python, c++, algorithm, syntax, fibonacci

I am trying to translate a Fibonacci algorithm I have in Python into C++, I have most of it working except I am screwing up somewhere on the syntax.

This is the Python version I currently have:

```
if n == 0:
    return (0, 1) *****
else:
    a, b = _fib(n // 2)
    c = a * (b * 2 - a)
    d = a * a + b * b
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return (c, d) *****
    else:
        return (d, c + d) *****
```

This is how I translated it into C++

```
int fib2(int n) {
 if (n == 0) {
    return (0, 1); *****
 }
 else {
    int a = fib2(n/2);
    int b = fib2(n/2);
    int c = a*(2*b-a);
    int d = a*a + b*b;
    if (n % 2 == 0) {
        return (c, d); *****
    }
    else {
        return (d, c + d); *****
    }
 }
}
```

I have put 5 stars where the error is coming from. If I understand it correctly, in the Python version, it is returning two Fibonacci numbers as a pair. However, when I try the same syntax in C++, it says "Expected expression".

I understand why this is happening, does anyone know how I could correct my C++ code so that it could return a tuple of two Fibonacci numbers as well?

Comment: the problem is that you cant return multiple values as a tuple in c++. best way to implement something like this is to use pointers

Comment: Make the return type a tuple or pair, and return {0, 1}

Comment: @RNar No need for pointers here, `std::pair` or `std::tuple` or `std::array<int, 2>` would each do the job nicely. Especially the array.

Comment: ^ or that. I'm not too well-versed in standard C++ types

Comment: @BaummitAugen Hi, thanks for your suggestion! It worked for the most part and I am no longer getting a compilation error regarding the return of the pair of numbers. Now I am getting an error saying that there is no viable conversion for 'int' to 'array<int,2>' when it is trying to calculate a and b. I get that it is having trouble because fib2 now returns an array but I declared a as an int. Is there an easy way to fix this?

Comment: @cursayer You can probably extend the answer below to arrays, or just use the answer with the pairs (although I would prefer the array, but the pair is not bad).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is a result using `std::pair`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

typedef pair<int,int> myPair;

myPair fib2(int n) 
{
    if (n == 0)            return make_pair(0, 1); 
    myPair r = fib2(n/2);
    int a = r.first;
    int b = r.second;
    int c = a*(2*b-a);
    int d = a*a + b*b;
    if (n % 2 == 0)        return make_pair(c, d); 
    else                   return make_pair(d, c + d); 
}

int main()
{
    myPair result = fib2(12);
    cout << "result:" << result.first << endl;
}
```